# Class must be either declared abstract or implement abstract method error

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am writing a Java application and I came across an error that wasn't supposed to be there. I have a class `FabriceBouncer` extending `HeartPG`, and `HeartPG` extends `PositionalGraphic`. This same class `FabriceBouncer` implements `Bouncer`. All the methods in `Bouncer` are implemented in `PositionalGraphic`, meaning that `FabriceBouncer` inherits all of them, but IntelliJ is giving me an error saying **Class 'FabriceBouncer' must be either declared abstract or implement abstract method**... I tried to invalidate cache/Restart but the error persists, I can't even run the application.

I need your support on this as I couldn't find anything tangible on the net. Note: It works on other IDEs.

Comment: Intellij says == it supposed to be this way. If you want more, provide your code.

Comment: It's a [duplicate of the support thread in IntelliJ IDEA forum](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000655944). User was asked to provide the code several times already, but the code is not provided so far.

Comment: Hit Alt-Enter on the underlined text, select "Implement Abstract Methods". That should give you an idea what methods are missing.

Comment: @Arkadiy user's point is that the problem is with IntelliJ IDEA and his code is fine since it builds in "other IDEs". Therefore it would be really interesting to see his actual code that builds in Eclipse, but not in IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Still, would be interesting to find out what methods IDEA thinks are missing.

Answer (score 1):

just follow the instruction in the error message (my guess ;) )
**Class 'FabriceBouncer' must be either declared abstract or implement abstract method...**

so, make 'FabriceBouncer' abstact

if this is not possible
 look for abstact methods HeartPG ans PositionalGraphic which are not implemented

if this dosn't help
look at methods in Bouncer interface and do the implementation